# What are PCs and PC tables in LibFuzzer

Tags: definition, instrumentation, fuzzing, libfuzzer

I am trying to understand how code instrumentation works in LibFuzzer.
From the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SanitizerCoverage.html), i get that I can choose different type of instrumentation with the option `-fsanitize-coverage`.

When starting the fuzzer, the `INFO` section indicates which instrumentation is used (here 8-bit counters)

```
...
INFO: Loaded 1 modules   (46994 inline 8-bit counters): 46994 [0x978cc0, 0x984452),
INFO: Loaded 1 PC tables (46994 PCs): 46994 [0x861098,0x9189b8)
...
```

It also mentions the number of loaded PC tables with the total PC number.
However, i have not found anywhere what does `PC` means in this context.
My guess so far is that it means "Program Counter" or "Path Coverage" but I have not found any source to confirm it.

My question is :
In the context of code instrumentation with LibFuzzer, what does "PC" means, and are there any sources to confirm it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, `PC` means `Program Counter` as explained in [this blog post](https://blog.code-intelligence.com/the-magic-behind-feedback-based-fuzzing)

> In order to log coverage, the function trace_pc will log the program counter. With this information, the fuzzer knows, which paths are traversed on the given input values. Each fuzzing engine runs through this process differently.